# Evenly space images?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have 4 images in a row, evenly spaced across the row depending on the width of the screen. I'd like to do this so I can have decent spacing between the images, without any horizontal overflow.

Comment: Great; sounds awesome. What have you tried?

Comment: Evenly, hmmm. Are the images same width?

Comment: @SalmanA yes. Say each of the 4 images is 100px wide and the screen is 1000px wide, there would be 600px of space divided between 5 "spaces" between each image, in space-image-space-image-space-image-space-image-space arangement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following layout will arrange the images as desired, assuming that the images are same width.

```
<div>
<div style="width: 25%; text-align: center;"><img src="img1.jpg"></div>
<div style="width: 25%; text-align: center;"><img src="img2.jpg"></div>
<div style="width: 25%; text-align: center;"><img src="img3.jpg"></div>
<div style="width: 25%; text-align: center;"><img src="img4.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

There is a catch; the gap before first and after the last image will be half compared to the gaps in-between:

```
 |  +----+    +----+    +----+    +----+  |
 |--|    |----|    |----|    |----|    |--|
 |  +----+    +----+    +----+    +----+  |
```

Answer (score 1):

Use tables for this:

```
<table width="100%">
 <tr>
  <td width="25%">IMAGE</td>
  <td width="25%">IMAGE</td>
  <td width="25%">IMAGE</td>
  <td width="25%">IMAGE</td>
 </tr>
<table>
```

and then add `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` as desired